# Reading in a txt file with no characters representing the end of a row. How do I iterate through the rows

Tags: python

I'm wanting to iterate through rows on the .gcode file. .gcode files are just text files used on CNC controlled machines...

I used the typical open() and read()

**Screenshot of open() and read()**

[image]

Here's what the .gcode looks like in Notepad.

**.gcode example**

[image]

When I attempt to iterate rows in this for loop, the for loop iterates through characters.

**Results from for loop**

[image]

Can someone help me out with what I am doing wrong here... Since there is no row delimiter, I am struggling with how to define the rows during the reading process or in some other process.

Comment: large file=>for line in f: small file=> for line in f.readlines()

Comment: Why did you bother creating, cropping, uploading, and linking screenshots, instead of just copy/pasting text? Please include code, data, and results as text, not images.

Comment: Use text and not images for the question's code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Difficult to give a precise answer without your code, but guessing from your screenshots try: `for line in data.split("\n"):`

Answer (score 4):

f.read() does not read the lines. It reads text as a continuous string. If you want to read line by line use f.readlines():

```
with open(source, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

You can also omit f.readlines() and directly do:

```
with open(source, "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        print(row)
```

However, according to Python's Zen:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Using the readlines() command is considered to be more Pythonic. Nonetheless, omiting this will make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Read mode is a default.

open returns file-like object, which is an iterator, that is possible to obtain for other iterable objects via call to `__iter__` method. Iterator can be iterated using `__next__` method or `next` built-in function. For loops just gets an iterator and calls method.

```
f = open('filename.ext')
f.__next__()  # line 1\n
f.__next__()  # line 2\n
next(f)       # line 3\n
f.__iter__() == f  # True. Iterator also has __iter__ method, but it will return iterator itself.
```

Each line ends with line separator, so you may consider using string `strip` method.

```
with open('filename.ext') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Do something.
```

Comment: It would help your answer if you explained more clearly that iterating over a file-like object causes it to be read one line at a time.  I do see that you kinda say this, but the behavior isn't really a function of the `for` loop itself, but rather a function of what happens when you iterate over a file-like object.

Comment: Edited this part.